# What is my profit per book?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Textbook problem:**

> I plan to print a large supply of calculus books. The manufacturing cost is \$$a$ per page (paper, printing) plus \$$b$ per book (cover, binding). I expect to sell a proportion $p$ of the books for \$$r$ per book and take the rest to the calculus book recycling plant, which will give me \$$s$ per page. What is my profit per book?

**Question:** Can this be solved without introducing a variable to represent "number of pages per book"?

My solution is
$$
P = pr + (1-p)sn - (b+an)
$$
where $n$ represents number of pages per book. The equation is "profit equals revenue from books sold plus revenue from books recycled minus printing costs for the cover and for the paper".

Comment: Well, your profit per book clearly depends on the number of pages in the book, so I can't see how you hope to leave that out of the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$P = pr + (1-p)sn - (b+an)$$

Your equation correctly represents the problem.

> **Question:** Can this be solved without introducing a variable to represent "number of pages per book"?

No, this problem cannot be solved without knowing the number of pages per book, $n$.